# Columnspan Doesn't Work in CustomTkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I'm new to CustomTkinter, I want to add entry in my page (inside a frame) but I also want to set the entry's size to span from left to right. I set columnspan=2 and sticky="we" the entry remains in the same size. I have tried to solve this but I just can't. Please help me why is the entry size isn't changing?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter as ctk
import pv_system_sizing_back as bk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Window
        self.daily_usage = None
        self.consumer = None
        self.title("PV System Sizing")
        self.geometry("1100x580")

        # Frames
        self.sidebar_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")

        self.center_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=200)
        self.center_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, padx=(20, 0), pady=(30, 30), sticky="nsew")

        self.result_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.result_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=4, padx=(20, 20), pady=(30, 30), sticky="nsew")

        # Grid layout
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # Sidebar buttons
        self.sidebar_button_ongrid = ctk.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="On-grid", height=30, fg_color="#3c3c3c",
                                                   command=lambda: self.ongrid_page())
        self.sidebar_button_ongrid.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

        self.sidebar_button_offgrid = ctk.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Off-grid", height=30, fg_color="#3c3c3c",
                                                    command=lambda: self.offgrid_page())
        self.sidebar_button_offgrid.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

        self.sidebar_button_hybrid = ctk.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Hybrid", height=30, fg_color="#3c3c3c",
                                                   command=lambda: self.hybrid_page())
        self.sidebar_button_hybrid.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

        self.sidebar_button_setting = ctk.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Pengaturan", height=30,
                                                    fg_color="#00698a")
        self.sidebar_button_setting.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 20))

        # Sidebar frame
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="PV System Sizing",
                                       font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

    def ongrid_page(self):
        self.delete_pages()
        self.consumer = ctk.CTkLabel(self.center_frame, text="Data Konsumen")
        self.consumer.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=25, pady=(15, 0), sticky="w")
        self.daily_usage = ctk.CTkEntry(self.center_frame, placeholder_text="Penggunaan energi listrik per hari (kWh)",
                                        height=30)
        self.daily_usage.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=(25, 25), pady=(5, 5), sticky="ew")

    def offgrid_page(self):
        self.delete_pages()

        self.consumer = ctk.CTkLabel(self.center_frame, text="Data Konsumen")
        self.consumer.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=25, pady=(15, 10))

    def hybrid_page(self):
        self.delete_pages()

        self.consumer = ctk.CTkLabel(self.center_frame, text="Data Konsumen")
        self.consumer.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=25, pady=(15, 10))

    def delete_pages(self):
        for frame in self.center_frame.winfo_children():
            frame.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `self.center_frame.columnconfigure((1,2,3), weight=1)` inside `__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with `columnspan` - it's doing exactly what it's designed to do. The problem is that columns 1, 2, and 3 all have a zero width.

By default, each row and column will be just big enough to fit the widgets in it. They don't grow to fit all of the available space. Since these columns are empty, they have a size of zero.

You can ask `grid` to allocate extra space to one or more of the column by giving the columns a weight. When you do that, any extra space in the parent widget (in this case, `self.center_frame`) will be allocated to the columns proportionate to their weight.

For example, if you want all extra space to be evenly distributed among the four columns, you can add this line of code:

```
self.center_frame.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)
```

If you want all extra space to go just to the last column, you would do it like this:

```
self.center_frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```